# How to download a PyTorch model as a file

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Pytorch version: 1.13.0

cuda version: 11.8

I am trying to create a ResNet101 model and cannot do it the usual way...

```
from torchvision.models import resnet101
model = resnet101(weights='DEFAULT')
```

... because the link is not whitelisted in the resource I'm using (I am getting 403 forbidden errors). I do not have the authority to change this.

So I tried downloading the model directly to my computer with this code...

```
import torch

url = 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet101-5d3b4d8f.pth'
model_path = 'PATH/resnet101.pth'

torch.hub.download_url_to_file(url, model_path)
```

(This code is to download the file to my local computer. I then upload it as a file to the VM I'm using)

```
model_path = Path("PATH/resnet101.pth")
model = torch.load(model_path)
```

(this code is to open the file in Jupyter notebook on the VM)

... but this is just downloading the state file and when I try `model.eval()` I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'eval'

How can I download the ResNet101 model as a file and then use it as a model in code?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.

First of all, next time when you ask a question related to the deep learning framework, you should provide more information about your framework version and CUDA version, it will help the community to understand your model better.

For your question, to load the model's parameters from Pytorch cloud, you can try to specify the version of weight that you want to use. For resnet101, there are two available. You can check it [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.resnet101.html).

Example below from my Pytorch 1.13.0 with CUDA 11.8:

```py
from torchvision.models import resnet101
model = resnet101(weights='IMAGENET1K_V1')
```

> AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'eval'

This problem raise because you're loading a Python dictionary and using it as a Pytorch Module. You can modify the code to fix it:

```py
model = resnet101(weights=None)

model_path = Path("PATH/resnet101.pth")
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
```

Pytorch provided a detailed tutorial for beginners about how the model is saved and loaded in [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

However, this does not solve my problem.

From your answer:

`from torchvision.models import resnet101
model = resnet101(weights='IMAGENET1K_V1')`
... I cannot do this because the resource I'm using blocks it.

Also, `torch.load_state_dict(model_path)` is not a function of torch. This function must be called on the model, which I do not have. From the documentation, I want to do what is under the "save/load the entire model" section. Where can I download the entire resnet101 model? All the resources I've seen have been state dictionaries only.

Comment: Also I just added torch/cuda versions to my answer

Comment: Firstly, I'm sorry, it was my mistake, I wrote the wrong syntax yesterday, I just edit it, please check and try again the `model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
`. To download the weights of the model to VM, you can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). Example `wget https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet101-5d3b4d8f.pth`